# Difference between Proteus results and KCL-deduced formula

Tags: proteus, wheatstone-bridge

I'm designing a small circuit using an op-amp for a temperature sensor (PT100).
I took the design online (see below).
[image]

I tried to find out the formula for finding the value Vout as a function of the input voltage.
I've used the KCL (I think it's Kirshoff-current-law) at the various junction points.
I got a formula that gives values that are offsetted by 0.2Volts from the output produce by a simulation of the circuit in Proteus (original diagram in LTSpice as seen in the picture above).
My question is: is it common for proteus to add an offset during the simulation, or am I necessarily making an error in my computations.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How about drawing a normal circuit with right angles at the very least?

Comment: Isn't this LTSpice, not Proteus?

Comment: Most definitely LTSpice

Comment: Do you know about net labels in LT spice? Hit the F4 key

Comment: @Nwells clean up your question, it's confusing, there is no way to answer it

Comment: @laptop2d it's been a while since I touched LTSpice... isn't "kaszanka" a net label?

Comment: @Kevin Don't know, I've never heard the word kaszanka in my life

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaszanka - Who would name a net like this?

Comment: 0.2 what?  Please place units on your numbers.

Comment: I think net names would be a way to avoid "kaszanka"

Comment: @Aaron, it's 0.2V. For example, from the formula, I get 0.22V for Vout, but on the simulation, it comes out as 0.42V. Tried different input voltage, I still get the offset of 0.2V.

Comment: @KevinKruse, it's proteus, I took the picture from a Polish website using LTSPice and migrated it as it to Proteus.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a pretty acceptable solution.
The formula for the output voltage of the diagram above is provided in another question, I've recently posted:
[Output Voltage Formula verification of Operational Amplifier circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/436459/output-voltage-formula-verification-of-operational-amplifier-circuit?noredirect=1#comment1089715_436459).
The diagram can easily be simulated in Proteus and provide a temperature range between 0 and 400 degree celcius.
[image]
Where Rx=R6=Resistance of the PT100 sensor.

The problem I was having was that I was wrongly connecting my PT100 (3-wires) RTD within the circuit (the above circuit assumes a 2-wire RTD).
The other mistake was to use a 5V supply source for the Op-Amp: no, the voltage source for the op-amp needs to be at least 6V. Preferably, the op-amp should be powered by a 6V and -6V as I still get wrong results with temperatures below 50 degree Celsius.
In my case, I'm mostly concerned with temperatures above 100 degree Celcius. So I'm fine with only a 6V supply for the Op-Amp.