# Output voltage formula verification of operational amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, kirchhoffs-laws, wheatstone-bridge, pt100

I'm trying to built an op-amp circuit for a PT100 temperature sensor. I've found the following circuit diagram online (from a polish website):

[image]

I'm trying to find the formula for the output voltage as a function of the input voltage.
I came up with the following formula (sorry, it's an image, no Latex here):

[image]

Can someone please help me verify that the last formula expressing Vout as a function of Vin is correct?

EDIT1: at the beginning of the demonstration, R1 and R2's values have been switched.

EDIT2: Please, this question IS NOT a duplicate of a previous question I've posted. In this question, I'm trying to verify that my computations are OK. In the other question I was trying to ask if it was common for Proteus to present results that slightly differ from the electric model.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Proteus results and KCL-deduced formula](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/436281/difference-between-proteus-results-and-kcl-deduced-formula)

Comment: I think there is an error in the OpAmp law: \$V_1 = V_2 = v\$ should be \$V_4 = V_2 = v\$

Comment: Rest of equations (including last steps) seem correct. Next step, expanding A and B. Good luck :)

Comment: @Huisman, you're right! but doesn't change the result! Thank you!!

Comment: @KevinKruse, the other question was about the difference between Proteus results and manual calculations. So no, it's no a duplicate, though related.

Comment: @G36, bla bla bla? Yes. Thanks to Polland!!

Comment: You **can** [use TeX for math stuff here.](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5565/most-common-mathjax-uses-in-electrical-engineering)

Answer (score 1):

The above design is an amalgamation of a Wheatstone bridge and a differential amp. It is hard to analyze and IMO an improper way to design a temperature sensor circuit. A better way is to have a wheatstone bridge followed by a diffamp as shown below:

[image]
Source: https://electronics360.globalspec.com/article/5424/design-notebook-linearization-of-a-wheatstone-bridge

The equations for that bridge are as follows:

[image]
Source: https://electronics360.globalspec.com/article/5424/design-notebook-linearization-of-a-wheatstone-bridge

Comment: The TS circuit is using positive feedback to linearization the temp pt100 sensor. http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt442/slyt442.pdf

Comment: @laptop2d, great answer, but sorry doesn't solve my problem. My circuit works pretty well on Proteus, although with slight different results. However, how do I find out the output voltage in your diagram?

Comment: @G36, thanks for the PDF link. Do you how I can get rid of VRTD in the formula presented in the document? Thanks.

Comment: @N.Wells As you can see the Author is using superposition principle to find the voltage at the noninverting input (V"+"). So, you need to do the same and find the expression for the inverting input (V"-") next set V"+" = V"-". http://www.ti.com/lit/zip/SLYT442

Comment: @G36, I read the attached files and I don't understand anything in it; yet, I'll give a try in a proteus Simulation and let you know ASAP.

Comment: @G36, as promised I've run the circuit into Proteus. I couldn't find the instrumentation amplifier components, so I settled for the Op-Amp diagram. I get very close values with an average error of +-0.1. I think it's good for me. I'll burn it on a perfboard and see how it goes live. Thank you!

Comment: @G36, If you post your comment as an answer, I'd accept it immediately. thanks again!

Comment: I don't care about the points. I'm glad that I could help.